# Managing a global DB connection in C++

Tags: c++, database-connection

Is is possible to do the following safely:

I have a C++ library which connects to SQL DB at various points.  I would like to have a global connection available at all of these points. Can this be done? IS there a standard pattern for this. I was thinking of storing a connection in a singleton.

Edit:
Suppose I have the following interface for the connection.

```
class Connection {
public:
   Connection();
   ~Connection();
   bool isOpen();
   void open();
}
```

I would like to implement the following interface:

```
class GlobalConnection {
public:
    static Connection & getConnection() {
        static Connection conn_;
        if (!conn_.isOpen())
            conn_.open();
        return conn_;
    }
private:
    GlobalConnection() {};
    Connection conn_;
};
```

I have two concerns with the above. One is that the getConnection is not thread safe and the other is that I'm not sure about the destruction of the static resource.  In other words, am I guaranteed that the connection will close (ie its destructor will be called).

For the record, the connection class itself is provided by the SQLAPI++  library (though that's not very relevant).

EDIT 2:  After doing some research it seems that while SQLAPI doent directly support pooling it can be used to enable connection pooling through the ODBC facilities via the call

```
 setOption("SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING") = SQL_CP_ONE_PER_DRIVER
```

The documentation says that that this call must be made before the first connection is established.  What is the best way to assure this in code with multiple potential call sites for opening a connection.  What if this doesn't happen?  Will an error be thrown or pooling just wont be enabled.
Also what tools are available for monitoring how many open connections there are to the DB?

Comment: If you're going to have just a global connection, the Singleton pattern could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

A Singleton can solve this in any OO language. In C/C++, you can also use a static variable (in case you don't use a pure-OO coding style).

Comment: a singleton is imho an [anti-pattern](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/337).but could be sufficient for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

most client libaries support [connection pooling](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_Pool).
so open a new connection will just pick a existing connection from the pool.

Comment: Thanks, This would save me a lot of trouble.  Do you happen to know how to enable it in SQLAPI++.

Comment: [look here](http://www.sqlapi.com/history.html) it is a feature since 2004. (look for SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING)

Comment: in addition: most libaries enable this feature by default.